# Is Neon coprocessor being used?

Tags: c, neon, beagleboard, fftw

I am using the FFTW3 library on Beagleboard xM in a C application to perform r2c FFTs of floats.  I read on [this](http://www.vesperix.com/arm/fftw-arm/) page that FFTW3 includes support for Neon, which is part of the xM architecture.

Is there a way to tell if the Neon coprocessor is actually being used?

For example, can I lists symbols from the object files and parse for some special Neon symbols?  Alternatively, can I look through gcc -S assembler output for any Neon instructions?  What instruction(s) would I look for?  (I'm not familiar with what Neon assembly looks like).

Comment: [`gcc -S`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#Overall-Options) is what you want for GCC's assembly output (which you could have Googled very easily).

Comment: I'm asking "Is that a valid way to determine that Neon is being used?" and also "What instruction should I even search for in asm?"

Comment: You should include that in the question. From here it looks as if you know what Neon instructions to look for, but not how to get the assembly output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the disassembly.  NEON instructions that operate on float data have a `.f32` suffix and the NEON registers have names of the form `dN` or `qN` (where `N` is an integer).  So if you see instructions that look like:

```
vadd.f32 q0, q1, q2
```

then NEON is being used.